# How to remove timestamp in XMLGregorianCalendar

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-dataformat-xml

I have a utility and when I run this utility in main method, I get the desired output. But when I convert that data into Xml format then I get output in timestamp format. How can I avoid this issue?

Utility for converting String to XMLGregorianCalendar

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, DatatypeConfigurationException {
        DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
        Date date = format.parse("2019-08-06 14:17:35");

        XMLGregorianCalendar xmlGregCal = null;

        GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        cal.setTime(date);

        xmlGregCal =  DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(cal);

        System.out.println(xmlGregCal);
    }
```

> Output in Java - 2019-08-06T14:17:35.000+05:30
>
> Ouput in XML - 1517769000000

I need same java time in xml output.

Using jackson to create XML file.

Comment: What is the type of that field in the xsd...

Comment: type="xsd:dateTime"

Comment: The utility isn't used in the conversion. Please show what and how you are converting things. Also how is this related to Spring Boot as there is nothing Spring Boot in there nor is there JAXB (as you are using jackson apparently).

Comment: I'm using utility for conversion and to create xml output Im using jackson. The jaxb auto generated class is used to set xmlgregoriancalendar date.

Comment: Please don't describe but add the actual code/test for conversion. The code shown  here is just a main method that doesn't have a relation to the actual conversion.

Comment: There is isn't any test code. All I can do is provide necessary details for you

Comment: Currently there is way too little information in your question to be able to even attempt to answer it.

Comment: I have jaxb class generated from xsd using jaxb maven plugin. When I want to display in xml output then I need to set string date in xmlgregoriancalendar format. Once this is set then generate xml file.

Comment: Again there is too little information, no code, no config you shown that is relevant to your question. Describing the issue isn't enough, show the code what you have tried (and the output). Also you claim jaxb, but you are using Jackson which isn't Jaxb. So why not use jaxb to generate XML in the first place? If you use jackson you have to configure it properly.

Comment: Based on minimal experience and possibly incomplete understanding I suggest that your solution will be to use [jackson-modules-java8](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8) and pass it an `OffsetDateTime`, not an `XMLGregorianCalendar`. If we’re to help you better, you need to post the code you use to have Jackson produce the output `1517769000000` in XML.

Comment: @OleV.V. can you provide a link for converting OffsetDateTime to XMLGregorianCalendar? Only XMLGregorianCalendar is expected in input and not any other date and time class.

Comment: From memory: `DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(yourOffsetDateTime.toString())`. But if Jackson prints a count of milliseconds when you give it an `XMLGregorianCalendar`, this won’t help you as far as I can see…